# Send a message to a computer on the same WiFi network

Tags: command-line, networking, wireless

I am at school and they all the machines use the same wifi... I wanted to ask how can I send a message from terminal or something to a girl that I like!

I only know the name of her computer, nothing else.

Answer (score 5):

If you can log into their computer remotely you can use `wall` which will print into most terminals (provided you have the privilege)

```
wall <<< Hi!
```

And honestly, if you have remote access, there are a dozen other ways you could do something to communicate. But yeah, that won't permeate the network naturally.

If remote access isn't an option:

- Why not use email or IM like normal people? :)
- Or, you could ask for their number and talk to them over the phone like we did in the late 90s...
- Or you could just "hang" like people did in the early 90s...
- I've no idea how people met before then. I imagine people were just running around and falling in love by accident. That's probably why everybody had big hair; to ensnare passers-by and strike up a conversation. I'm sure Wikipedia probably has some archaeological bits on dating.

As an introverted internet denzian for much of my life, I can sympathise with the remote drive-by approach to dating but unless you're just trying to harass somebody, there's a lot to be said for talking to them in real life. Scary, for sure, but worth it.

And welcome to Ask <strike>Ubuntu</strike> Somebody Out For Me.